# Delete site from Chrome's preloaded HSTS list

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, hsts

Is there any way to remove entries from Chrome's preloaded HSTS list?

For development reasons I need to route a webpage `google-analytics.com` which refers to different from the original ip address. But `google-analytics.com` is on Chrome's preloaded HSTS list. This results in an error while loading web page, because my ssl of `google-analytics.com` certificate does not properly signed.

I know that I can remove entries from the dynamically created HSTS list via chrome://net-internals/#hsts - but not entries that come with the browser.

Is there any way to tell Chrome that I know what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1):

If you have create your own CA, create the certificate for google-analytics.com with this CA and import the CA as trusted into the browser/CA store then it should work. It will ignore pinning information if the certificate is signed by an explicitly imported CA.

See also [Man in the middle attack to a website which uses public key pinning](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124998/man-in-the-middle-attack-to-a-website-which-uses-public-key-pinning).

Comment: How i can do that? Can you help? Just first steps.

Comment: @MishaPolitaev: search for [how to create own CA](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+CA+mitm&oq=howto+create+own+CA)

Comment: Thank for all! https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/index.html found the best ever step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 0):

Nope: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=483634

You could try using a self-signed cert but imagine they preload pinning as well for their sites so doubt that would work either.

Answer (score 0):

1) Navigate to chrome://net-internals/#hsts
2)First, to confirm the domain's HSTS settings are recorded by Chrome type the host name into query domain section. Click the query button. If the box returns found with settings information below, the domains HSTS settings are saved in your browser.

For your purpose(if you want to delete):
3)Type the same domain name into the DELETE DOMAIN section and click Delete button.

Your browser will no longer force an HTTPS connection for that site! You can test the working by refreshing of navigating to that site.

Comment: The question was about preloaded entries. What you describe explicitely does not work for those.

Comment: tested and confirmed, this does not work for sites on the preloaded list